# Primefaces Push Private Channel wrong room/user/user/user/

Tags: primefaces, push, atmosphere, socketchannel

When I'm testing the primefaces(5.2) push example (counter, notify, photoshared) all work completely, except chat ([same code from page primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.xhtml), copy paste the code from example page), here occur a detail:

1. username:"felipe" **log in** (private message work)

> private channel = /pushmob/primepush/{room}/felipe

2. username:"felipe" **log out**
3. username:"felipe" log in (private message not work)

> private channel = /pushmob/primepush/{room}/felipe/felipe

Another user login can't send private message to felipe.

For detect to private channel, i use in console
PF('subscriber').cfg.request.url

Any idea???

PrimeFaces 5.2

Atmosphere 2.3.4

Same code from chat example.

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

index.xhtml

```
<p:socket onMessage="handleMessageChat" channel="/{room}"
            autoConnect="false" widgetVar='subscriber' />
```

chatview.xhtml

```
public class ChatView implements Serializable {

private final static String CHANNEL = "/{room}/";

public void sendGlobal() {
    eventBus.publish(CHANNEL + "*", username + ": " + globalMessage);

    globalMessage = null;
}

public void sendPrivate() {
    eventBus.publish(CHANNEL + privateUser, "[PM "+ username + "] " + username + ": "
            + privateMessage);
    eventBus.publish(CHANNEL + username, "[PM " + privateUser + "] " + username + ": "
            + privateMessage);
    privateMessage = null;
}

public void login() {
    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if(users.contains(username)) {
        loggedIn = false;
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Username taken", "Try with another username."));
        requestContext.update("growl");
    }
    else {
        users.add(username);
        requestContext.execute("PF('subscriber').connect('/" + username + "')");
        loggedIn = true;
    }
}

public void disconnect() {
    //remove user and update ui
    users.remove(username);
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:users");

    //push leave information
    eventBus.publish(CHANNEL + "*", username + " left the channel.");

    //reset state
    loggedIn = false;
    username = null;
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...I had to create two pages, one for login and another for chat, allowing successfully use the private channel.